# GIT: how do i do a partial merge from one branch to another one?

Tags: git

I have commits A-B-C-D on one branch
and want to merge A-B-C to another one.

I know that you could do git cherry-pick one by one, and my question is whether I could group these commits together and hopefully do a squash.

Comment: If you could diagram your desired outcome, I could give you a walk-through of the commands to get there.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Like [Autocracy](https://stackoverflow.com/users/90322/autocracy) said, [git rebase](http://git-scm.com/docs/git-rebase) is probably what you want.

*An example:*

Let's say you have `A-B-C-D` and want to merge `A-B-C` to `Y`.
Creates a clone of `C` and rebase the clone onto `Y`:

```
git checkout -b C_copy C
git rebase --onto Y A~1 C_copy  # <= --onto [target] [source] [what]
```

Check if everything went well and resolve conflicts on your way if necessary.

Now you've got `C_copy` on top of `Y`, like this: `Y-[A_copy]-[B-copy]-C_copy`

You could edit that with an interactive rebase e.g. to squash it (assuming you're still on `C_copy`):

```
git rebase -i HEAD~3
```

If something goes awry, you can just throw away `C_copy` as it does not affect `C`.

Now you can either fast-forward `Y` to `C_copy` or merge it using `git merge --no-ff` (specify `--no-commit` to edit your commit if you wish):

```
git checkout Y
git merge --no-ff [--no-commit] C_copy
```

Answer (score 2):

Shouldn't `git checkout branch-to-merge-on; git merge tag-or-sha1-of-commit-c` work?

The following does as I expect:

```
git init
touch init; git add init; git commit -m 'init'
git checkout -b abcd
touch a; git add a; git commit -m 'a'
touch b; git add b; git commit -m 'b'
touch c; git add c; git commit -m 'c'; git tag commit-c
touch d; git add d; git commit -m 'd'
git checkout master
touch e; git add e; git commit -m 'e'
git merge commit-c
```

resulting in

```
init -- e -- merged   <- (master)
 \           /   
  a -- b -- c -- d    <- (abcd)
```

This merges *everything* (up until a common ancestor (init) in this case) before c, but it looks like this is what you want to do.  If not, then `git rebase`ing a-b-c-d elsewhere might be appropriate.

Comment: This works, if the OP’s DAG matches your assumption. It may not be desirable if there are other commits between `init` and `A` that the OP does not want to “merge”.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest thing is

```
git branch featureX C
git checkout branch_to_merge_to
git merge featureX
```

optionally add `--squash` to the merge command if you want to squash.

This assumes that the parent of A is the merge base. If it isn't, you aren't merging.

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

The solution of wnoise looks like the better one, and can be combined with git rebase for completion.

```
init -- e --  a -- b -- c (merged)   <- (master)
  \                    /
   \             -----
    \           /   
     a -- b -- c -- d    <- (abcd)
```

If you don't want 'a' on master then you use rebase easier:

```
git rebase -i init
```

and discard the unwanted commits

```
init -- e -- b -- c (merged)   <- (master)
```

Answer (score 0):

The best way about this is to use `git rebase -i`. You can do so with a new branch if you feel like preserving the history. You can also rebase onto the existing base and use the interactive session to squash or skip commits, then merge that if you want it to appear as a merge instead of direct commits.

Comment: he wants to merge, not rebase anything.

Comment: `cherry-pick` doesn't result in a merge. The question is ambiguous, especially when he mentions squashing the commit.

Answer (score 0):

You could do `git cherry-pick --no-commit A B C` then do the commit.